# Tree Recursion: How to get the parent root of the selected tree node

Tags: javascript, json, recursion, dictionary, tree

I have a tree-like structure of a json object

```
{
  "saxena": {
    "chewning": {
      "betten": {},
      "ching": {},
      "kelley": {}
    },
    "kobrinsky": {
      "karniely": {},
      "naveh": {},
      "rozenfeld": {},
      "shalom": {}
    },
    "schriever": {
      "brinker": {},
      "mcleland": {},
      "merrick": {}
    },
    "vacant": {
      "akers": {},
      "carlton": {
        "marvin": {}
      },
      "fox": {
        "glover": {
          "clements": {},
          "koya": {}
        },
        "holden": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "bill": {
    "phil": {
      "bob": {},
      "smith": {},
      "hello": {}
    },
    "bye": {
      "ok": {},
      "hmm": {},
      "no": {},
      "alright": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The root names are saxena and bill. I would like to create a function that can determine the root name of who the user searches for.

For the most simplest case, if they search for saxena, it returns saxena. If they return bill, it returns bill.

For a more complex case, saxena will be returned if the user searches for any of the names under her.

For example, if I search for betten, akers, glovers, or koya, saxena will be returned.

And if I search for bob, smith, or alright, bill will be returned.

This is my work so far. I tried using recursion, but for some reason when I find the selected name, I return an undefined.

```
var findRootName = function(data, ltmName) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (key == ltmName) {
            return key;
        } else {
            findNode(data[key], ltmName);
        }
    }
}

var findNode = function(data, ltmName) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (key == ltmName) {
            return key;
        } else {
            findNode(data[key], ltmName);
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gthnfta7/7/

Can somebody help me and figure out why my recursive function isn't working?

Comment: Please insert the javascript for your question directly into your question.  External references as the only reference to your code are not permitted here at StackOverflow because they have a habit of disappearing or changing over time which then render the question useless for future readers and Stackoverflow wants to be an important reference of information, not only for the original person asking the question, but also for many people that come after.

Comment: You should do it THIS time or your question may get closed.  Use the "edit" link to modify your question and insert the relevant code into the question.

Comment: Much better.  Now your question has longer lasting usefulness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're not returning anything in the event that the node is found. You can simplify your function by writing it like this:

```
var findParent = function(data, childName) {
  for (var key in data) {
      if (key === childName || findParent(data[key], childName)) {
        return key;
      }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

An alternative technique, if you need to make many calls over the same data, is something like the following:

```
function makeSearcher(data) {
    var paths = (function makePaths(data, parentPath, store) {
        var path = parentPath || [];
        results = store || {};
        Object.keys(data).forEach(function(key) {
            var newPaths = path.concat(key);
            results[key] = newPaths;
            makePaths(data[key], newPaths, results);
        });
        return results;
    })(data);
    return function(key) {
        var path = paths[key];
        return path && path[0];
    };
}

var search = makeSearcher(data);

search('clements'); //=> 'savena'
```

Note that the internal `makePaths` function is broader than the use here, as it could also be use to return a result like

```
[ "saxena", "vacant", "fox", "glover", "clements" ]
```